# discord.js bot autocomplete slash command error

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

```
const { EmbedBuilder, ApplicationCommandType } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'animal',
    description: "A test command for autocomplete slash command.",
    type: ApplicationCommandType.ChatInput,
    options: [
        {
            name: 'animal',
            description: 'Choose an animal.',
            type: 3,
            required: true,
            autocomplete: true
        }
    ],
    autocomplete: (interaction, choices) => {
        const data = {
            '908385923673231481': ['dog', 'cat', 'rabbit'],
            '967751631695405097': ['lizard', 'horse', 'hamster']
        }
        data[interaction.guild.id].forEach(animal => {
            choices.push({
                name: `${animal}`,
                value: `${animal}`
            });
        });
        interaction.respond(choices).catch(console.error);
    },
    run: async (client, interaction) => {
        const animal = interaction.options.get('animal').value;
        if(animal) interaction.reply({ content: `${interaction.user}, You chose **${animal}**!` });
    }
};
```

i am using node versone v16.13.2 and latest discord.js when i run my code it is showing **/home/runner/Discordjs-v14-bot/slashCommands/fun/animal.js:21
data[interaction.guild.id].forEach(animal => {
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')
at Object.autocomplete (/home/runner/Discordjs-v14-bot/slashCommands/fun/animal.js:21:36)
at Client. (/home/runner/Discordjs-v14-bot/events/interactionCreate.js:11:24)
at Client.emit (node:events:390:28)
at Client.emit (node:domain:475:12)
at InteractionCreateAction.handle (/home/runner/Discordjs-v14-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/InteractionCreate.js:81:12)
at Object.module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (/home/runner/Discordjs-v14-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/runner/Discordjs-v14-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:355:31)
at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/runner/Discordjs-v14-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:447:22)
at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/runner/Discordjs-v14-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:304:10)** and in discord its showing loding opctions fail

Comment: Have you tried to check the value of `interaction.guild.id`?

Comment: can you please console.log `interaction.guild.id` and `data[interaction.guild.id]`. Also, you said "loading options failed".. can you show us how you handle your **`autocomplete`** event?